# Can I use a crystal with smaller PPM value?

Tags: embedded, crystal

The manufacturer recommends that I use a crystal with a tolerance of +-100ppm. Can I use a crystal with +-20ppm for better accuracy?

Comment: If I told you that you can't use a **more accurate** crystal, would you believe that? Would you ask **why**? Think about buying a lot of 100ppm crystals and measuring them all, now from those we select all of the crystals that have a tolerance of 20 ppm or better. Can we use those crystals or not?

Comment: will your MCU perform better? you will not achieve lower phase noise with a tighter tolerance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, yes. Tighter tolerance is never worse than wider tolerance. Besides, if the frequency is 20ppm off, there is no way for the board to know you're using a +-100ppm part or +- 20ppm part. :^)

If we're talking about high volume production, than you're probably wasting money by using a more expensive tighter tolerance part.